# DJango model -Exception on crate :TypeError(\"save() got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I was building my api in DJango and  rest framework . Please see my model file

```
class StaffUser(models.Model):
    staff_id=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    user=models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='staffs')
    roles=models.ManyToManyField(BranchRole,related_name='holding_staffs')
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'staff_details'
 
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        email =kwargs['email']
        password=kwargs['password']
        del kwargs['email']
        del kwargs['password'] 
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.user=User.objects.create_user(
            email=email,
            password=password,
            is_staff=True,
            is_active=1
        ) 
        super(StaffUser,self).save(**kwargs)          
        return self
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

When I am trying to call this save function in viewset , I am getting following exception.

"Exception on crate :TypeError("save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'"
Please help me to resolve this error. Please see my code in viewset

```
class StaffUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):   
    
    """
    This api deals all operations related with module management
    You will have `list`, `create`, `retrieve`,
    update` and `destroy` actions.
    Additionally we also provide an action to update status.
    """
    serializer_class = StaffUserSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    queryset = StaffUser.objects.all()


       
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)        
        self.ARG={
        'staff_id':str,
        'phone_number':str,
        'email':str,
        'name':str,
        'password':str,
        'address':str,
        'id':int,
        'roles':dict,   
        }
    
        self.REPLACING_VALUES={
        'model_name':'content_type__model_name',
        'content_type_id':'content_type__id',
        'app_name':'content_type__app_label' ,
        'app_label':'content_type__app_label'
        }
        self.DEFAULT_PARAMETERS={
           'content_type__status__active':True
        }
        self.VIEW_PARAMETERS_LIST=[

        ]
        self.detailed_view=False
        # if any  user argument having another label that model relation
        # will replace the smame with replacement values"""     
        self.api_model=StaffUser()

    def create(self, request):
        #over ride create method in view set

        status='Sucess'
        # set up detailed view is False
        # alter this value to True if you need to alter thsi
        content=[]
        message="Sucessfull Created"
     
        try:
            query_params = data_formatter.request_to_dic(request.POST) # custom method to get input as dictionary
            print(query_params)#it works
            if (query_params is not None):
                input_params=data_formatter.convert_type(query_params,self.ARG) #it works-custom method for convert
                print(input_params)
                validated_value=validations.is_data_valid(input_params,{'arg':self.ARG})#it works-custom method for convert
                print(validated_value)
                if(validated_value==1):
                    #To create group based on name    
                    staff_obj=StaffUser().save(                        
                        **input_params
                        )             
           
                else:
                    status='Fail'               
                    message=validations.ERROR_MESSAGES[validated_value]
        except Exception as e:
            message='Exception on crate :'+repr(e)
            status='Fail'        
        return Response({"status":status,"data":content,"message":message})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're using the wrong signature of `save()`

instead of

```py
staff_obj=StaffUser().save(**input_params)
```

you should use

```py
staff_obj=StaffUser.objects.create(**input_params)
```

or

```py
staff_obj=StaffUser(**input_params) 
staff_obj.save()
```

Read carefully [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods)

One more thing, you can rewrite this

```py
email =kwargs['email']
password=kwargs['password']
del kwargs['email']
del kwargs['password']
```

in this way

```py
email = kwargs.pop('email')
password = kwargs.pop('password')
```

**UPDATE**
Honestly not sure it'a a good idea to do this job in the `save()` method; why don't create a model's classmethod ?

```py
@classmethod
def create staff_user(cls, **kwargs):
    email = kwargs.pop('email')
    password = kwargs.pop('password')
    kwargs['published_date'] = timezone.now()
    kwargs['user'] = User.objects.create_user(
            email=email,
            password=password,
            is_staff=True,
            is_active=1
        )
    return cls.objects.create(**kwargs)
```

and then call it in your View

```py
staff_obj = StaffUser.create_staff_user(**input_params)
```

?

Comment: Thanks for the response. let me check that

Comment: I am getting another while excute that code. Exception on crate :TypeError(\"StaffUser() got an unexpected keyword argument 'email'\"   I have override save methods , email,password parameters is used to create user obj in StaffUser.

Comment: updated the answer, I'd suggest to NOT override the `save()` method

Comment: Thanks Bro, It works, But I couldn't figure out exact problem to override that save method.

Comment: well, as you can read from the doc, the save method accepts specific parameters while you where passing you inputs